# command to apply changes in react for ubuntu server

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

I have a ubuntu server with nginx, gunicorn, django and react. 
I simply change this code to one of projects modules in the server.

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

to

```
<p>changing test </p>
```

now I want to see results, but webpage is still same as before.
what should I do? is there an equivalent for `service gunicorn restart` in react to apply changes?

Comment: Hi, `service gunicorn restart` is a command to restart Django web server service, and it has nothing to do with React code, to be able to run your changes to React files you have to rebuild the React components source, in your front-end files you will have package.json file, inside it there is a script section that contains the script to re-compile your react source files.

Comment: Does your react application has webpack server or is the app is created using create-react-app CLI the you should get updated output on the screen while your `npm start` script is running on your command line.

Comment: it returns error failed to compile although the site is perfectly working. @KrinaSoni

Answer (score 0):

If your react server is up and running, saving changes to your module should be enough to update your web-page, have you saved your changes?

Comment: yes, I have been saved it, actually, I have pulled it from gitlab

Answer (score 0):

The nginx web server needs to be reloaded (not restarted) then only it will reflect the changes.

Following code will reloaded the service

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

or

```
service nginx reload
```

Following link can help you understand why you need to reload instead of restart: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-linux-gracefully-reload-restart-nginx-webserver/